# What is the best way to two way sync MYSQL remote and local databases

Tags: mysql, database, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a situation wherein I want to sync remote and local MYSQL databases.

Local DB is connected to local application and remote DB is connected to remote application.

So records in both DB get updated or inserted separately.

Database schema is same.

What is the best option to keep both databases in sync?

Comment: This sounds like a potential nightmare to me.  Reason being, if an insert should succeed on one but fail on the other, how would you even handle that?  Maybe see if you can use a single database everywhere.  You can always partition if you need more space.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: There is such requirement, is it possible somehow?